# Изменение классов в fla

Tags: flash, apache-flex

Как можно редактировать классы в fla или swc?
Дело в том что есть библиотека UI (GUI) в формате fla, swf+list.xml, swc, а как редактировать сами классы я никак не пойму (во FlashDevelop отображаются только имена констант и функций), к сожалению папки с классами как таковой нету. Есть какая-то программа позволяющая отредактировать их?

Comment: библиотека скомпилирована. Никак.